# What does a rooted forest look like?

Tags: graph-theory

I have heard the term *rooted forest* used in graph theory (I can't seem to find a good source to link, though). It seems like it is a collection of subgraphs of a directed acyclic graph, with each subgraph having a root.

Can someone draw a rooted forest for me?

Comment: A rooted tree is a tree with one vertex distinguished, called the root.  A forest is a union of one or more trees.  I've never heard the term rooted forest; [this paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/graphgeometry/papers/f.pdf) calls it a forest with a root for each connected component (i.e. a collection of rooted trees).

Comment: @vadim123 Thanks! On another note, a forest is a union of one or more trees -- is there a term for a union of one or more directed acyclic graphs?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph